# Blazor Telerik DropDown List does not display as expected

Tags: c#, telerik, blazor

My Blazor dropdown list is coded as below:

```
<TelerikDropDownList Data="@BkAccounts" TextField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.DisplayField))" ValueField="@(nameof(BkAccounts.BIC))" Value=1 Width = "250"></TelerikDropDownList>
```

It displays as is the attached screenshot.

[image: Basic displaying]

[image: when I click on it:]

The 250 width correctly applied on what is displayed when I click on the DDL, but the basic displaying does not seem to apply the correct width??
What did I miss?

Comment: You miss to provide the code you try so far. Without code we cannot help you.

Comment: ops sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noob mistake!

```
Width = "250"
```

must be changed to ----->

```
Width = "250px"
```

Comment: Or to another CSS unit, many are supported. See more at https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/common-features/dimensions